# How to deactivate firefox right-click when I am on a Google Drive document?

Tags: firefox, context-menu, right-click, google-drive

When I use Google spreadsheet document I use to right-click to add comments for instance.
But each time I right-click the firefox context menu is display over the spreadsheet context menu.
So how to not display the firefox context menu only when I am on a Google Drive document ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Go to Firefox Options, the click Content, Advanced (next to Javascript), and check `Disable or replace context menus`.

Comment: For Firefox 30  : see http://kb.mozillazine.org/JavaScript#Advanced_JavaScript_settings